# IBDesignable can't set background on buttons

Tags: xcode, swift, ibdesignable

I'm trying to create a custom button in my IOS project. But when I'm creating the button with the my class the background doesn't work in the storyboard. But when I run the program the button works fine.

Here you see my class

```
@IBDesignable class GreenButtonTest : UIButton{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        style()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        style()
    }

    private func style() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor(CGColor: "#6eb18c".CGColor)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your button set to type custom?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override prepareForInterfaceBuilder() and call style() from there too.

Try this:

```
@IBDesignable class GreenButtonTest : UIButton{

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        style()
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        style()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        style()
    }

    private func style() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }

}
```

Comment: where do i know this changes are made??

Comment: i mean where do i see this changes on apple documentation, how do i realize there is a change on the documentation

Comment: You can for example watch the WWDC session videos to learn what's new: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2015/

Comment: Actually no, you dont need to do this